# Name of "one project per business domain" pattern?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture

I'm creating a website using ASP.NET MVC 5 (maybe this is irrelevant).  But I have heard about this way of structuring the solution where you have one project (repositories, factories, models, presentation) per business domain.

Does any one know what this pattern is called? And what are some good examples?

Comment: I have never heard of this, but it sounds like a quick way to have an absurd number of projects depending on what you define as a business domain and a crazy amount of dependencies to manage for higher (above the business domain) projects.

Comment: @Tommy I'm not so sure Tommy. A way of avoiding this dependency mess could be to use the Stable Dependencies Principle and dividing your solution into Domain projects and Framework projects. This would allow for a very modular, plug and play solution. Still, it would be nice to see some example.

Comment: Are you hinting at a DDD Bounded Context?